# ConEmu - environment variable TEMP set automatically

Tags: windows, conemu

I have a rather annoying problem with ConEmu 180309 (and with a few versions before that as well): In my consoles the TEMP environment variable is automatically set to the ConEmu directory which messes up some of my applications - e.g. Java writes some process info there which jvisualvm tries to lookup. That fails of course, because jvisualvm looks in the actual TEMP directory while Java writes to ConEmu's TEMP.

Example:

- `echo %TEMP%` in a normal terminal yields `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp`
- `echo %TEMP%` in a ConEmu terminal yields `C:\Tools\ConEmu\Data\Temp` (that's where I put ConEmu portable)

Changing TEMP inside the ConEmu terminal sometimes works but it's rather annoying that I have to remember this.

I couldn't find any setting to change, documentation or any other online resource on that problem yet. 

Does anyone know this problem and preferably a solution (besides not using ConEmu)?

Btw, I'm starting my ConEmu instances like this:

```
C:\Tools\ConEmu\ConEmuPortable.exe /cmd @C:\Users\myuser\Documents\ConEmuTasks\conemu_settings.txt
```

Comment: Try ConEmuPack.7z instead of protableapps format

Comment: @Maximus now I get you, instead of using the app launcher I have to directly use ConEmu64.exe, then it works. Thx for the hint.